# Use a C++ string in z3::expr?

Tags: c++, z3

I got difficulties in using Z3::expr. In z3, the expr *conj* can be defined like:

```
expr x = c.bool_const("x");
expr y = c.bool_const("y");
expr conj = (!x || !y);
```

Is there a way to use a string variable to define *conj*? Something like:

```
expr x = c.bool_const("x");
expr y = c.bool_const("y");
string str = "(!x || !y)";
expr conj = some_API(str);
```

I got stuck on the problem for days.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use that particular string in the example, but you can use [`parse_string`](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classz3_1_1context.html#a31dafd9d9d944828e020c9d7d5694b08), which understands strings in SMT2 format.