# How to transfer constraints of string type to z3 solver expr in C++?

Tags: c++, string, api, z3

For example, I got a constraint: "(number < 10) && (name == "hello")";
I can do the following now:

```
context c;
expr number= c.int_const(number);
expr name = c->string_val(name.c_str());
expr constrain = ***procedure***("(number < 10) && (name == \"hello\")");
```

How can I implement this ***procedure()***?

there is an incomplete and unproofed answer in [Use a C++ string in z3::expr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51063153/use-a-c-string-in-z3expr), and I still can not figure out how to implement it?

I am very eagered and appreciateed for your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#include <z3++.h>

using namespace z3;
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  context c;
  expr number = c.int_const("number");
  expr name   = c.constant(c.str_symbol("name"), c.string_sort());
  expr hello  = c.string_val("hello");

  expr constraint = number < 10 && name == hello;

  solver s(c);
  s.add(constraint);
  cout << s.check() << "\n";
  cout << s.get_model() << "\n";

  return 0;
};
```

Assuming you put the above in a file called `a.cpp`, you compile it like this:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 a.cpp -l z3
```

And when run, it produces:

```
sat
(define-fun number () Int
  9)
(define-fun name () String
  "hello")
```

## Using higher-level APIs

As you no doubt noticed, programming z3 in C/C++ is very verbose and terribly error prone. Unless you've some other reason to use C/C++, I'd recommend using a higher-level API, such as Python or Haskell, which simplifies programming in z3 to a great extent.

### Python

For instance, you'd code your problem in Python like this:

```py
from z3 import *

number = Int('number')
name   = String('name')

s = Solver()
s.add(number < 10, name == "hello")
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

producing:

```
sat
[number = 9, name = "hello"]
```

### Haskell

And in Haskell, it would look like:

```hs
import Data.SBV

ex :: IO SatResult
ex = sat $ do number <- sInteger "number"
              name   <- sString  "name"

              constrain $ number .< 10 .&& name .== literal "hello"
```

producing:

```
*Main> ex
Satisfiable. Model:
  number =       9 :: Integer
  name   = "hello" :: String
```

## Summary

Long story short, programming z3 in C/C++—while entirely possible—is something that's best avoided if you can use a higher-level interface. If you must stick to C/C++, be sure to study the API: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3.html

Comment: Thanks for your answers ！ But it doesn't solve my questions. In my encountered scenario, the constraints are variables. The program should handle with different inputed constraints iteratively, so i must use a string variable to receive constraints.Now I dont know how to transfer this constriants of string type to context expr?

Comment: Morever, i'd like to try z3 in c++ first, because it's more efficient than that in python

Comment: Z3 does not know or support the language you use in your strings. You either have to teach it that language (see @alias' answer) or you have to use a different language (e.g. SMT2).

Comment: As @ChristophWintersteiger mentioned (and he is a coauthor of z3, so there's authority there!), how would z3 know what your language means? `parse_string` won't help you, even if you stick to SMTLib in that language, because so far as I know it won't create the variables for you; you'd have to provide all the contextual info. You really need to write a parser for your "string-language" (whatever it is) and translate it to z3 calls.

Comment: Re: efficiency: I'd still strongly recommend using Python/Haskell, heck even Java over  C. For one thing, the "efficiency/" you'll get from c/c++ is really overrated: The interfaces in higher-level languages have come a long way and while there's a bit of overhead, I'd be surprised if it mattered for most projects out there: Solver time should dominate all of that. And secondly, for doing the "extra" work of parsing/representing/coding your original issue (whatever it might be) adds so much more complexity that you don't just want to use the low-level API for that. This is my experience.

Comment: @alias Thanks for detailed explanations! I will try python instead!